# How to migrate the whole database from Postgres to DynamoDB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-dynamodb, database-migration, dms

I have a database in PostgreSQL. Now we need to import whole database into DynamoDB. Data Migration service need to be used for this purpose or any other service can be used. Please explain in detail.

What is the strategy to be followed? I have studied many blogs but I couldn't get any proper way to migrate the whole database from PostgreSQL to DynamoDB. Only through DMS Service is it possible to migrate or any other service can be used to migrate or any script should be run to migrate the PostgreSQL to to DynamoDB.

Comment: Are you sure you wish to do this? DynamoDB is _not_ a relational database, so the application that uses the data would need to be rewritten. You would also likely want to change the way that the data is stored. Have your application developers created a proof-of-concept against a subset of the data to confirm that it will be useful?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Ya...everything is done....we are trying to migrate the Whole DB from PostgreSQL to dynamo DB...It is very tedious...we are not sure which service to use and how to use it..please help me

Comment: @ John whether it is possible to migrate the whole db from postgreSQL to synamo DB?

Comment: Well, if the AWS Data Migration Service can do it, then that sounds like a good idea. Did you have a problem with it?

Comment: Ya...I don't know where to start how to do that...I didn't find the full tutorial to do that..Please help me...

Comment: @John we are trying hard to do that...please help us to do that

Comment: 1. [Getting Started with AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_GettingStarted.html) 2. [Using a PostgreSQL Database as a Source for AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html) 3. [Using an Amazon DynamoDB Database as a Target for AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html)

Comment: @John The links are complete tutorial? If i face any problem i will reach out to u ...pls help me

Comment: @John Is there any specific type of file extension....only that can be imported into the dynamo db or...what is the format that can be imported into the db

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/?nc=bc&pg=rs) offers everything you would need to migrate data from any relational DB into AWS - whether the target is DynamoDB (NoSQL offering from AWS) or any of the DB flavors from AWS RDS service.

You can find multiple migration playbooks and step-by-step guides on the [Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/resources/?nc=sn&loc=5) page of this AWS service